# How do I extract id from Django queryset in admin update method?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-queryset, mptt

I need to get the `id` of an object as I update it in the Django Admin.

I've tried `get()` and have printed out the queryset using vars(queryset), but I can't seem to isolate the value I need.

I've tried to iterate over it, but to no avail. I should mention I'm using MPTT, so it's a `TreeQuerySet`. But I don't think that matters.

In admin.py:

```
class JokeAdmin(MPTTModelAdmin, ImportExportModelAdmin):

    ...   ...


    def reviewed_approved(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(reviewed=True, approved=True)
        print(vars(queryset))
```

this is the output:

```
{'model': class 'blog.models.Joke','_db': None,'_hints': {},'query': <django.db.models.sql.query.Query object at 0x033404D0>, '_result_cache': None, '_sticky_filter': False, '_for_write': True, '_prefetch_related_lookups': (), '_prefetch_done': False, '_known_rel
ated_objects': {}, '_iterable_class': class 'django.db.models.query.ModelIterable', '_fields': None}
```

Answer (score 1):

I realized I could obtain the object id from the request:

```
        id = request.POST.get('_selected_action')
```